# soap fault 'Input String Not In Correct Format'

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I try to use web service between c# server and php client.

When i use web service without arguments all works!

But when i want to pass arguments to function i have this error:
SoapFault : Le format de la chaîne d'entrée est incorrect

My wsdl file:
https://pastebin.com/ti805zkW

My php code:

```
public function previewAction(Request $req)
{
    $client = new \SoapClient("http://localhost:1664/WebReport/Service/?wsdl");
    $preview = $client->Preview(array('id' => 1, 'choice' => 2, 'userDate' => 'test'));
    return new JsonResponse($preview);
}
```

My c# Iservice code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WebReport
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool Reload();

        [OperationContract]
        bool Treatment();

        [OperationContract]
        Dictionary<string, float> Preview(int id, int choice, string userDate);
    }
}
```

My c# service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebReport
{
    public class Service : IService
    {
        public bool Reload()
        {
            //Application.GetInstance().ReloadConfig();
            return true;
        }

        public bool Treatment()
        {
            //DataPoints.Treatment.GetInstance().run();
            return true;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, float> Preview(int id, int choice, string userDate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{ 0}.{ 1}.{ 2}", id, choice, userDate);
            Dictionary<string, float> test = new Dictionary<string, float>();
            test.Add("2017-05-04 10:10:10", 100000);
            test.Add("2017-05-05 10:10:10", 100001);
            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

I have test to extract php class from wsdl file with wsdl2phpgenerator but same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP developer, but in testing my own APIs with PHP I accept an object in the controller, not an argument for each array item.

So create a class with properties that match the array and take that as one argument to the controller.

```
public class PreviewDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int choice { get; set; }
    public string userDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller:

```
public Dictionary<string, float> Preview(PreviewDTO prev)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{ 0}.{ 1}.{ 2}", prev.id, prev.choice, prev.userDate);
    Dictionary<string, float> test = new Dictionary<string, float>();
    test.Add("2017-05-04 10:10:10", 100000);
    test.Add("2017-05-05 10:10:10", 100001);
    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer.

I've found my problem.

I've replace this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{ 0}.{ 1}.{ 2}", id, choice, userDate);
```

by this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}", id, choice, userDate);
```

Space in string parameter.